# Constant DFSR traffic

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dfs-r

Last week one of our servers (Server01) hung up. After rebooting, DFS successfully recovered the database, and files are syncing fine. However, ever since then, we've had fairly constant DFS traffic from Server02 (at another site) back to our main site. I can't tell for sure that it's to Server01 (it could be to another server at our main site, and I'm seeing the traffic via Cacti), but it's very steady.

There are no errors in the logs. I've looked at the DFS debug logs but don't see anything jumping out. I have clean rebooted Server02 with no change (waiting for the weekend to reboot servers at our main site). Running a backlog or replicationstate check with dfsrdiag shows no backlogged files anywhere, and no active transfers. All servers are 2008 R2.

Any ideas how to find out what is transferring, and to stop it?

Answer (score 1):

You can reconfigure [DFSR debug logging](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958893) on `Server02` to see what it is *actually* doing if the current log files do not provide a full picture of what's happening:

```
WMIC syntax: wmic /namespace:\\root\microsoftdfs path dfsrmachineconfig set debuglogseverity=5
```

But as the article notes, a severity level of 4, which is default, is sufficient in most cases.